# Почему возможен поиск элемента линейном списке

Tags: c, структуры

У меня вопрос по поводу функции поиска.Вот в главной программе создается указатель `Node *a = NULL;` , куда запишется адрес очередного последне-созданного "вагончика".А когда функция add закончит создавать цепочку , она вернет указатель на последний "вагоничик".То есть в `а` теперь лежит адрес последнего из цепочки , а после него  дальше только NULL.
А потом вызывается функция Find.И как она может делать поиск , если был передан адрес **последнего** элемента цепочки, а не первого? Поэтому мне не понятно почему `head = head->next;` не утыкает всё в NULL. Где я в своих рассуждениях ушел не туда ?

```
    struct Node {
    int Data;
    Node* next;
};

Node* add(Node *head, int Value)
{
    Node *New = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    New->Data = Value;
    New->next = head;
    return New;
}


Node* Find(Node *head, int Value)
{
    while (head)
    {
        if (head->Data == Value)
            return head;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}



int main()
{
    Node *a = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        a = add(a, i);

    Node *del = Find(a, 2);
```

Comment: У Вас вставка идет в начало списка, а не в конец. Чтобы вставить в конец, нужно пройти список до конца, потом вставлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `add` всегда добавляет новый "вагончик" в самое *начало* списка. При каждом вызове она возвращает указатель на новое *начало* списка. Таким образом, указатель `a` всегда указывает на *самый первый* "вагончик" в списке, а не на самый последний, как вы неправильно полагаете.

Функция `Find` начинает поиск с `a`, то есть с начала списка и просматривает весь список до конца.

Comment: А что определяет то, что она вставляет в начало списка ?

Comment: @Elvin: Реализация функции `add` определяет. Там черным по белому реализована вставка в начало списка.

Comment: а так и должно быть , что в начало списка ? И еще вопрос: это всё из-за него  ?  New->next = head;

Comment: Из-за него. Сами же написали: присвоить следующий New->next = head; Новый поставили перед существующим.

Comment: @Elvin: Ну это уж у вас надо спрашивать - как должно быть. Откуда же мне знать, куда вам надо вставлять.

Comment: @JaponDemon,можете объяснить подробнее , всё равно не вижу , как это происходит New->next = head;

Comment: @Elvin, не нужны Вам мои объяснения.  это всё давно уже разжевано, в интернете материала полно. Сам бился со списками месяца два -- не доходило и всё. А потом, как-то само собой, как с неба свалилось ... сел, нарисовал на листочке и разобрался.

Comment: @Elvin, head - это указатель на первый элемент. Вы этот указатель кладете в поле next нового элемента. Получается, что старый первый элемент становится вторым (следующим за новым). А новый элемент становится первым.